# How to keep some variables static for the summary in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am using the following dataframe in R:

df<-

```
structure(list(uid = c("K-1", "K-1", 
"K-2", "K-3", "K-4", "K-5", 
"K-6", "K-7", "K-8", "K-9", 
"K-10", "K-11", "K-12", "K-13", 
"K-14"), Date = c("2020-03-16 12:11:33", "2020-03-16 12:11:33", 
"2020-03-16 06:13:55", "2020-03-16 10:03:43", "2020-03-16 12:37:09", 
"2020-03-16 06:40:24", "2020-03-16 09:46:45", "2020-03-16 12:07:44", 
"2020-03-16 14:09:51", "2020-03-16 09:19:23", "2020-03-16 09:07:37", 
"2020-03-16 11:48:34", "2020-03-16 06:23:24", "2020-03-16 04:39:03", 
"2020-03-16 04:59:13"), batch_no = c(7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 
7, 6, 7, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7), marking = c("S1", "S1", "S2", 
"SE_hold1", "SD_hold1", "SD_hold2", "S3", "S3", "", "SA_hold3", "S1", "S1", "S2", 
"S3", "S3"), seq = c("FRD", 
"FHL", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "ABC", NA, NA, NA, NA, "DEF", NA)), .Names = c("uid", 
"Date", "batch_no", "marking",
"seq"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

And using below-mentioned base R solution to convert the df into a summary table.

```
# Function to summarise each of the vectors required: summariser => function
summariser <- function(vec) {
  within(unique(data.frame(
    vec = vec,
    counter = as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(vec), sum(is.na(vec)),
                     ave(vec, vec, FUN = length))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )),
  {
    perc = paste0(round(counter / sum(counter) * 100, 2), "%")
  })
}
# Vectors to summarise: vecs_to_summarise => character vector
vecs_to_summarise <- c("seq", "marking", "batch_no")

# Create an empty list in order to allocate some memory: df_list => list
df_list <- vector("list", length(vecs_to_summarise))

# Apply the summariser function to each of the vectors required: df_list => list of dfs
df_list <- lapply(df[,vecs_to_summarise], summariser)

# Rename the vectors of each data.frame in the list: df_list => list of dfs: 
df_list <- lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(i) {
  names(df_list[[i]]) <- gsub("_vec", "",
                              paste(names(df_list[i]), names(df_list[[i]]), sep = "_"))
  return(df_list[[i]])
})


# Determine the number of rows of the maximum data.frame: numeric scalar 
max_df_length <- max(sapply(df_list, nrow))

# Extend each data.frame to be the same length (pad with NAs if necessary): df_list => list
df_list <- lapply(seq_along(df_list), function(i){
  y <- data.frame(df_list[[i]][rep(seq_len(nrow(df_list[[1]])), each = 1),])
  y[1:(nrow(y)),] <- NA
  y <- y[1:(max_df_length - nrow(df_list[[i]])),]
  if(length(y) > 0){
    x <- data.frame(rbind(df_list[[i]], y)[1:max_df_length,])
  }else{
      x <- data.frame(df_list[[i]][1:max_df_length,])
      }
  return(x)
  }
)

# Bind the data.frames in the list into a single df: analysed_df => data.frame
analysed_df <- do.call("cbind", df_list)
```

Problem Statement:

I am creating a dataframe by using `sys.date()`. Now it is possible that for a particular date some or all variables are not available for either `batch_no`, `marking` or `seq`.

The question is, I want to keep some variables for column `batch_no`, `making` and `seq` static in the `analysed_df` irrespective of if some of or all those variables are available in the dataframe for that particular date.

If those variables are not availabe for the particular date then the count and percentage would be 0 and 0.00% respectively for that particular variable.

The Output:

```
seq      count  percentage   Marking     count     Percentage     batch_no   count    Percentage
FRD      1      12.50%       S1          2         25.00%         6          1        12.50%
FHL      1      12.50%       S2          1         12.50%         7          2        25.00%
ABC      2      25.00%       S3          1         12.50%         8          2        25.00%
DEF      1      12.50%       Hold        2         25.00%         9          1        12.50%
XYZ      1      12.50%       NA          1         12.50%         NA         1        12.50%
ZZZ      1      12.50%       (Blank)     1         12.50%         (Blank)    1        12.50%
FRD      1      12.50%         -         -           -             -         -           -
NA       1      12.50%         -         -           -             -         -           -
(Blank)  0      0.00%          -         -           -             -         -           -
Total    8      112.50%        -         8         100.00%         -         8         100.00%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R Solution:

```
# Vector containing the all unique elements of the uid vector: 
# unique_ids => character vector:
reporting_vars <- c("seq", "marking", "batch_no")

# Empty list to store all unique reported vector's values: report_struc_list => list
report_struc_list <- vector("list", length(reporting_vars))

# Populate the list: report_struc_list => list
report_struc_list <- lapply(df[, reporting_vars], function(x){sort(unique(x))})

# Simplify to a data.frame: report_struc => data.frame
report_struc <- cbind(
  data.frame(lapply(report_list, function(x) {
    length(x) <- max(lengths(report_list))
    return(x)
  })),
  counter = 0,
  perc = 0
)

# Order the reporting data.frame: report_struc_ordered => data.frame
report_struc_ordered <- report_struc[, c("seq", "marking", "batch_no", 
                                         "counter", "perc")]

# Function to generate reports, input data.frame: analysed_df => data.frame
report_func <- function(df){
  # Function to count elements and calculate perc of total: 
  # analyse_func => function
  analyse_func <- function(df, vec){
    vec_summary <- data.frame(lapply(within(
    merge(rbind(setNames(
      aggregate(
        rep(1, nrow(df))~vec,
        df,
        FUN = sum,
        na.action = na.pass
      ),
      c(gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(
        substitute(vec)
      )), "counter")
    ), c(NA, sum(
      is.na(df[, gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(vec)))])
    ))),
    report_struc_ordered[!(report_struc_ordered[, gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(vec)))]
                           %in% vec),
                         c(grep(
                           gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(vec))),
                           names(report_struc_ordered),
                           value = TRUE
                         ),
                         "counter", "perc")],
    all = TRUE),
    {
      perc = paste0(round(counter / sum(counter) * 100, 2), "%")

    }
  ), as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  # Append a total to the bottom of the data.frame: vec_summary => data.frame
  vec_summary <- setNames(rbind(vec_summary,
                       c("TOTAL",
                         as.character(sum(
                           as.numeric(vec_summary$counter)
                         )),
                         as.character(paste0(
                           sum(as.double(gsub(
                             "\\%", "",
                             vec_summary$perc
                           ))),
                           "%"
                         )))), c(gsub(".*\\$", "", deparse(substitute(vec))),
                                 paste(gsub(".*\\$", "", 
                                             deparse(substitute(vec))), 
                                        names(vec_summary)[2:ncol(vec_summary)],
                                       sep = "_")))
  }

  # Apply the function to each of the vectors required: vec_summ_list => list
  vec_summ_list <- list(
    seq_df = analyse_func(df, df$seq),
    marking_df = analyse_func(df, df$marking),
    batch_no_df = analyse_func(df, df$batch_no)
  )

  # Store a scalar containing the row count of the data.frame
  # with the most rows in the vec_summ_list: max_df_length => numeric vector
  max_df_length <- max(sapply(vec_summ_list, nrow))

  # Extend each data.frame to be the same length 
  # (pad with NAs if necessary): vec_summ_list => list
  vec_summ_list <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(vec_summ_list), function(i){
    # Replicate the amount rows required to be padded: y => data.frame
    y <- data.frame(vec_summ_list[[i]][rep(seq_len(max_df_length - nrow(vec_summ_list[[i]])), 
                                           each = 1),])
    # Nullify the rows: y => data.frame
    y[1:(nrow(y)),] <- "-"

    # If necessary bind the replicated rows to the underlying data.frame:
    # x => data.frame
    if(length(y) > 0){
      x <- data.frame(rbind(vec_summ_list[[i]], y)[1:max_df_length,])
    }else{
      x <- data.frame(df_list[[i]][1:max_df_length,])
    }
    # Move the total row to the bottom of the data.frame: x => data.frame
    x[nrow(x),] <- x[which(grepl("TOTAL", x[,1])),]

    # Nullify the total row thats not the last row: x => data.frame
    suppressWarnings(if(length(which(grepl("TOTAL", x[,1]) < nrow(x))) > 0){
     tmp <- x[which(grepl("TOTAL", x[,1])),]
     x[which(grepl("TOTAL", x[,1])),] <- as.character("-")
     x[nrow(x),] <- tmp 
    }else{
      x
    })

    # Define the return object: 
    return(x)

  }
  ), names(vec_summ_list))

  # Flatten the list into a data.frame: analysed_df => data.frame
  analysed_df <- Reduce(cbind, vec_summ_list)

}

# Store an empty list to contain each unique date: df_list => list
df_list <- vector("list", length(unique(df$Date)))

# Store an empty list to hold the daily reports: report_list => list
report_list <- df_list

# Split the data.frame into many data.frames by date: df_list => list
df_list <- split(df, df$Date)

# Store the base report as a list element for each date: report_list => list
report_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) report_func(x))
```

Data:

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      uid = c("K-1", "K-1", "K-2", "K-3", "K-4", "K-5",
              "K-6", "K-7", "K-8"),
      Date = structure(
        c(
          1584321093,
          1584321093,
          1584321093,
          1584321093,
          1584321093,
          1584321093,
          1584321093,
          1584321093,
          1584321093
        ),
        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
        tzone = ""
      ),
      batch_no = c(7L,
                   7L, 8L, 9L, 8L, NA, 7L, NA, 6L),
      marking = c("S1", "S1", "SE_hold1",
                  "SD_hold2", "S1", NA, NA, "S2", "S3"),
      seq = c("FRD", "FHL",
              "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ", "ABC", "ZZZ", NA, "FRD")
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-9L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

Comment: Getting output like `structure(list(seq = structure(1:6, .Label = c("ABC", "DEF", 
"FHL", "FRD", "XYZ", "ZZZ"), class = "factor"), marking = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, NA), .Label = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "SD_hold2", 
"SE_hold1"), class = "factor"), batch_no = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
NA, NA), counter = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), perc = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), .Names = c("seq", "marking", "batch_no", "counter", "perc"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")` using the shared sample data.

Comment: Each day's report is stored as a data.frame in a list. To look at the first days' report (in RStudio) use View(report_list[[1]]). Or to view the contents in the console use report_list[[1]].

Comment: The data.frame you are looking at is the base report containing all unique values for seq, marking and batch_no -- this is the base report from which we can can ensure that the values in the days report are static.

Comment: @SophiaWilson do you understand?

Comment: If you want to push each data.frame to the Global environment use:  list2env(report_list, .GlobalEnv)